# How does R grab arguments passed from Python

Tags: python, r, arguments, subprocess

I would like to run the R script from Python. The scripts below works when without "+ args". Anyone has idea what's wrong in passing the args?

Python script:

```
import subprocess

Iterations = 10
command = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/bin/Rscript.exe'
path2script = 'C:/Users/a0266997/Documents/PossionDistribution.R'
args = [str(Iterations)]
cmd = [command, path2script] + args
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

R script:

```
myArgs <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
Iterations = myArgs[0]
Iterations

do something in R ....
```

Comment: One problem I see in your R code is that you are using `myArgs[0]`, it should be `myArgs[1]` as R vectors begin with 1 not 0. Of course python starts from 0 so this is an easy mistake to make going between both languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with some corrections that should work for you. I also changed the R code to be something that should be reproducible (e.g. printing to stdout and stderr).

I changed the `subprocess.Popen(cmd)` call to `subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)` which should fix part of the problem. There is a fix in the R code as well.

```
import subprocess

Iterations = 10
command = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/bin/Rscript.exe'
path2script = 'C:/Users/a0266997/Documents/PossionDistribution.R'
args = [str(Iterations)]
cmd = [command, path2script] + args
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
results = p.communicate()
```

R Script (modfied version of your code)

This has `myArgs[0]` changed to `myArgs[1]`

```
myArgs <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
Iterations = myArgs[1]
write(paste0("stdout: ", Iterations),  file = stdout())
write("stderr",                        file = stderr())
```

I ran this on Mac OS and it worked for me. It should at least get you started in the right direction, depending on the details of your needs.

Comment: One option you may want to look into is `rpy2`. This may make the handing of data between Python and R easier. I haven't used it for a while but it worked fine when I did.